# Apple VOIP Notification expiry not working

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, voip, callkit

I am working on callkit, voip notification is recieved using expiry value 0. As soon as I set expiry to 30 seconds voip notification is not receiving.

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "content-available": 0,
            "sound": "default",
            "apns-push-type": "voip",
            "apns-expiration": 1619519427,
            "apns-priorty": 10
        }
    },
    "callId": 952537,
    "callType": "video",
    "from": "abcd1234",
    "notificationId": "C_c53bab22-2e30-4149-8f3f-4e82a624ba7b"
}
```

When "apns-expiration" is set to 0 it works but when its set to anytime in utc voip not recieved. I dont want to recieve voip after 30 seconds.

Comment: You shouldn't set the expiration to more than 30 seconds. It doesn't make sense for a call. "Set the value of the apns-expiration header field to 0, or to only a few seconds. Doing so prevents the system from delivering the notification at a much later time." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/responding_to_voip_notifications_from_pushkit

Comment: I already tried 30 seconds still not recieving

Comment: Have you tried 2 seconds? Really, it doesn't make sense to specify a value other than 0 for a VoIP push. Either the device can be notified "now" about the incoming call or it can't.

Comment: I want the voip to deliver after 30 seconds.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. It isn't a delay; it won't deliver *after* the expiration time, it will deliver until the expiration time, but seriously if the device isn't online and ready to receive a call when the call is available, it probably won't be online in 30 seconds time.  A VoIP push should be deliverable and actionable immediately otherwise it should be discarded.

Comment: if the user is offline voip is sent and when he comes online after some time callkit open due to voip so I want to convert it into miss call notification whenever it comes after 30 seconds. We have to open callkit at any cost else app crashes

Comment: I don't think that is a supported use case for voip push.